# Symfony (5.1) Doctrine Event Listener is fired but not Entity Listener

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony5, symfony-eventdispatcher

Using [Symfony official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-entity-listeners),
I was cleaning up some code and wanted to replace a Doctrine event listener in Symfony (working):

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\Comment;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class CommentAuthorAssignmentListener
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function prePersist(Comment $comment, LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        dump($comment, $event); exit;
        $comment->setAuthor($this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser());
    }
}
```

```
services:
    App\EventListener\CommentAuthorAssignmentListener:
        autowire: true 
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

With a more specific Entity listener (no error but not fired up at all):

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\Comment;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class CommentAuthorAssignmentListener
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function prePersist(Comment $comment, LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        $comment->setAuthor($this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser());
    }
}
```

```
services:
    App\EventListener\CommentAuthorAssignmentListener:
        autowire: true 
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.entity_listener , entity: 'App\Entity\Comment', event: prePersist }
```

Some notes:

- I did run `cache:clear`
- Use case: explicitely persisting (a freshly created) *Comment*

Comment: Have you done the ritual clearing of the cache?  And I assume you are in fact creating a new comment and explicitly persisting it?  Have you tried using dump:container just to double check your service is being tagged as expected and not somehow being overwritten?

Comment: @Cerad Indeed, I did both (just edited the question).  But didn't look at dump:container. I will check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you made a typo:

```
 # these are the options required to define the entity listener
 name: 'doctrine.orm.entity_listener'
 event: 'postUpdate'
 entity: 'App\Entity\User'
```

Notice the ".orm." in the tag name, so for your use case:

```
services:
    App\EventListener\CommentAuthorAssignmentListener:
        autowire: true 
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener , entity: 'App\Entity\Comment', event: prePersist }
```